# Generic Constraints on function

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I want to write a generic function that has a constraint on the type. Specifically I want something like this:

```
bool IsInList<T>(T value, params T[] args)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach(var arg in args)
    {
        if(arg == value)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
 }
```

The point being that you can check if an item is in a parameter list viz:

```
if(IsInList("Eggs", "Cheese", "Eggs", "Ham"))
```

However, the compiler croaks on the equality line. So I want to put in a constraint on the type that it implements IEquatable. However, constraints only seem to work at the class level. Is this correct, or is there some way to specify this generically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generic constraints work on generic methods as well:

```
bool IsInList<T>(T value, params T[] args) where T : IEquatable<T>
```

BUT, `IEquatable<T>` doesn't define `operator ==`, only `Equals(T)`.

So, you should use `Equals()` and you don't even need the constraint for that: `Equals(object)` is member of `object`.

Also don't forget that `Equals` won't work if the object is `null`.

Comment: You can use `object.Equals(a,b)` instead of `a.Equals(b)` so that you don't need to worry about null objects.

Comment: Now if only MS would update their documentation to reflect this reality, rather than giving everyone the impression that the constraint is only valid for class declarations.

Answer (score 11):

Others have mentioned `IEquatable<T>` which is certainly a good potential constraint.

Another option to remember is `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, which will use `IEquatable<T>` if available, but fall back to `object.Equals(object)` otherwise. This means you can use it with types which predate generics but override `Equals`, for example:

```
bool IsInList<T>(T value, params T[] args)
{
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    bool found = false;
    foreach(var arg in args)
    {
        if(comparer.Equals(arg, value))
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Note that the default equality comparer also copes with null references, so you don't need to worry about those yourself. If type `T` hasn't overridden `object.Equals(object)` or implemented `IEquatable<T>`, you'll get reference equality semantics (i.e. it will only return `true` if the exact reference is in the array).

A few other points:

- Your desire to stick to a single exit point makes the code less readable, IMO. There's no need for an extra variable here:

  ```
  bool IsInList<T>(T value, params T[] args)
  {
      IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
      foreach (var arg in args)
      {
          if (comparer.Equals(arg, value))
          {
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
  ```
- LINQ already contains a method for this, `Contains`, so you can simplify the code to:

  ```
  bool IsInList<T>(T value, params T[] args)
  {
      return args.Contains(value);
  }
  ```
- `Array` effectively contains this functionality too, with `IndexOf`:

  ```
  bool IsInList<T>(T value, params T[] args)
  {
      return Array.IndexOf(args, value) != -1;
  }
  ```
- Your method is perhaps a little misleadingly named, given that `args` is an array, not a `List<T>`.

Comment: +1 for the very detailed answer, but I think you have a typo in your first code: if(comparer.Equals(arg == value)) - I think it should be if(comparer.Equals(arg, value)).

Comment: @ShdNx: Whoops, absolutely :)

Comment: Isn't `IndexOf` just a static method on `System.Array`?

Answer (score 1):

The `==' operator is generally used for immutable types only - (built-in value types or custom immutable types that have overloaded the == operator.  Unless you overload it, if you use it on reference types, (except strings) it only returns true if both variables point to the same instance of the type (same object).  It would return false if the two veriables point to different instances of the type even if they both have all the same internal data values.

So You need to restrict the type T to those types that implement the `Equals()` function, which  is intended to determine whether two instances of any type are "equal" and not just that they both point to the same instance...  and use that instead.
The built-in interface `IEquatable<T>` expresses this for you. (kinda like `IComparable<T>` requires that a type has a `CompareTo()` function)
Also,  you can make your function much terser and clearer...

try this:

```
bool IsInList<T>(T value, params T[] args) where T:IEquatable<T>
{ 
    foreach(var arg in args)          
        if(value.Equals(arg)) return true;
    return false;
 }
```

You should also understand the difference between Equals() and == and decide which is more appropriate for whatever your intent is... Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx) reference for more info.

Comment: That doesn't work, `IEquatable<T>` doesn't contain `operator ==` and it's not somehow magically created either. Also, `Equals()` works even without `IEquatable<T>` (although it's `Equals(object)` and not `Equals(T)`).

Comment: Yes, but you can't expect to have the compiler implement the code for an Equals method for you on any arbitrary custom type you have defined. You have to write that code yourself. This constraint just restricts you from calling the method on types that have not implemented this method. And, yes, also, you are correct in that the == operator is not in IEquatable my mistake, I edited to correct that... Check out the link I added for more info.

Comment: No, it's not quite the same thing. The signature of `IEquatable<T>.Equals` isn't the same as `object.Equals`. By constraining it this way, you're preventing it from working on types where the default equality comparison works perfectly well. Basically there's unfortunately no way of saying, "constrain T to a type which has a custom equality comparison" - your current constraint is too narrow, and "no constraint" is arguably too wide.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
arg == value
```

with

```
arg.Equals(value)
```